# Creating an IDictionary<string,Expression> proving difficult

Tags: linq

I want to make a dictionary that has named LINQ Expressions, since I cannot store the expressions in my database. I will store the name of the expression that is needed, and a structured `IList<T>` where `T` is a parameter type that can be stored in the database.

But it isn't quite working how I want ... I've got the following layout. This isn't a real expression, I'm just trying to get something to compile for now..

```
public static class Evaluations {
        public static Dictionary<string, Expression> Expressions = new Dictionary<string, Expression> {
            {
                "First Expression",
                new Expression<Func<int, int, int>> =
                    (current, next) => (current + next)
            }
        };
    }
```

However I am being told ... well, pretty much nothing. The compiler errors make no sense. Simply stating

> This is not a variable

How can I add a `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` as the `Value` of my `IDictionary<string, Expression>` safely? Any suggestions?

Comment: are you sure you need expression? you can just use Func<T1,T2,T3> if you don't need the Linq.Expression stuff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a valid expression:

```
new Expression<Func<int, int, int>> =
                (current, next) => (current + next)
```

What are you trying to assign a value to?

I think you mean:

```
(Expression<Func<int, int, int>>)((current, next) => current + next)
```

This compiles fine:

```
public static Dictionary<string, Expression> Expressions = 
    new Dictionary<string, Expression> {
    {
        "First Expression",
            (Expression<Func<int, int, int>>)((current, next) => current + next)
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes, it was the boxing of the Expression part that wasn't working for me. Thanks.

Comment: @Ciel: There was no boxing going on, and still isn't... it was just the syntax which was causing you a problem.